# Fedora 25 - Place terminal icon on Desktop

Tags: fedora, icons

It seems adding desktop icons are a pain in Fedora. Can someone please tell me how I can place the Terminal icon on the desktop ? I have downloaded the **gnome-tweak-tool** and enabled icons on Desktop.

Also is there an application that I can use to do this ? Rather than editing the files in ~/local ?

Comment: It would have been better to include which desktop environment you're trying this with. Are you using traditional GNOME instead of GNOME Shell?

Comment: @bitofagoob Which ever one comes as default. I guess traditional gnome

Comment: @ng.newbie  GNOME3 is the current default desktop on Fedora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've logged out & back in after enabling desktop icons in the tweak tool; using the gnome file browser, go to:

```
/usr/share/applications
```

Search for, or find the file called 'terminal' in this directory, and drag it to the desktop.

Comment: Sir you are awesome. It worked